# Can you make a blob triggered azure function app that only binds the filename, not the whole blob?

Tags: azure-functions

My function only needs to know the filename of a new blob.  My blobs are huge and give an ‘out of memory exception’.  As far as I can see, the blob trigger downloads the whole blob.  Is this possible?
Thanks all.

Comment: Can you provide more information on which blob you are getting this or code

Answer (score 0):

> Can you make a blob triggered azure function app that only binds the filename, not the whole blob?

Yes, this is possible, you can only get the name of the blob when the azure function gets triggered.

Below is example C# azure Function Blob trigger, which triggers even when i upload 1gb file:

**`Function.cs:`**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp74
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("test/{name}", Connection = "rithconnection")] Stream stream, string name)
        {
            
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} ");
        }
    }
}
```

**`Local.settings.json:`**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "rithconnection": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik89;AccountKey=+CBlDa47+AStWfNXlw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

**`host.json:`**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

When i upload a blob it got triggered:

[image]

[image]

You can also work with Python , java also for these triggers.

**`My csproj:`**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UserSecretsId>ae5657fd4fa5-a94d-cdcf5b0c608a</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.11.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for that.  I just tried it and I'm getting this error...

Result: Failure Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionInputConverterException: Error converting 1 input parameters for Function 'MyBlobFunction': Cannot convert input parameter 'myBlob' to type 'System.IO.Stream' from type 'System.ReadOnlyMemory`1

Comment: I am working in .net7 are you? I am have given my csproj too, use my code entirely, you will get output as I have got.